# UITableView with multiple sections and a UIButton

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITableView` with two sections.  Each section has a few `UITableViewCells`.  I'd like to put a `UIButton` between the first section and the second section.  **Should the button be in it's own section? or perhaps in the third cell of the first section?**

**Edit #1**:  perhaps it's easiest to just use add another section with a single cell and style it like a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that depends on how it's set up and how you want it to look.  If you're in a plain table, I think it shouldn't really matter because there's no space between sections.  If you're using a grouped table, it's probably easiest and best-looking to put the button in its own section.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in either its own section or in a cell. How you display the button visually (and its semantic meaning) might affect your choice.